# Java Game Development: Weird Movement bug

Tags: java, eclipse, youtube

I've been following these tutorials on how to make a top down shooter in java from [Foreign Guy Mike](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_IV37n-uBpRp64hQIwywWQ) on youtube, in eclipse.

But I ran into a weird bug where the player could move diagnally when not shooting, but when the player shoots, they **can't** move to the north and west **at the same time**, I looked a little deeper but I couldn't find anything.

Here is the player movement code:

```
if(left) {
    dx = (0 - speed);
}

if(right) {
    dx = speed;
}

if(down) {
    dy = speed;
}

if(up) {
    dy = (0 - speed);
}

x += dx;
y += dy;

if(x < r) x = r;
if(y < r) y = r;
if(x > GamePanel.WIDTH - r) x = GamePanel.WIDTH - r;
if(y > GamePanel.WIDTH - r) y = GamePanel.WIDTH - r;

dx = 0;
dy = 0;

if(firing) {
    long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - firingTimer) / 1000000;
    if(elapsed > firingDelay) {
        GamePanel.bullets.add(new Bullet(270, x, y));
        firingTimer = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

And here is the entire bullet class:

```
package games.duphus.wave;

import java.awt.*;

public class Bullet {
private double x;
private double y;
private int r;

private double dx;
private double dy;
private double rad;
private int speed= 10;

private Color color1;
public Bullet(double angle, int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    r = 2;

    rad = Math.toRadians(angle);
    dx = Math.cos(rad) * speed;
    dy = Math.sin(rad) * speed;

    color1 = Color.YELLOW;
}

public boolean update() {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    if(x < -r || x > GamePanel.WIDTH + r || y < -r || y > GamePanel.HEIGHT + r) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(color1);
    g.fillOval((int) (x - r), (int) (y - r), 2 * r, 2 * r);
}
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: the player movement logic looks ok, its probably something in the place where you fire the bullet (`firing=true`) or change the movement (`left=true`,`right=true`...ect).

Comment: Does it allow other directions while firing? Such as South and East? Or any other diagonal direction?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at the code very much, but I think you have a keyboard ghosting issue. I can't tell you how to fix this except change which keys you use for firing and moving.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not complety sure about it, but I think it has to be with the keys sense. When you press the third key, it forget the first one that you pressed. I did the same tutorial and that's what I conclude.